# Can we add route automatically in app.routing.ts when component is created?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular6

I want to add a route automatically in app.routing.ts file whenever new component is created.

Comment: Recently, I have done a mobile app with angular 8 and the routes are automatically created, when I created a new component.

Comment: @Nirmalya How you were doing that ?

Comment: I did that via npm and the command is
-- ionic generate component login
and the generated path will be..
--  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule) },

I have used ionic 4.

Comment: @Nirmalya Right, bu it is creating new module and routing every time. I don't want that. I want to add route in existing app.routing.ts.

Answer (score 2):

With Angular CLI version 8.1 you can do:

```
ng g module home --route home --module app.module
```

ref: [generating a module with angular cli](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

The command above will:

1. Generate a lazy-loaded module called HomeModule
2. Insert a lazy route in app.module.ts
3. Generate an eager default route inside the HomeModule
4. Generate a component that will handle the eager default route

In most cases you will need to edit the file by hand, but it's not difficult, just copy-paste app-routing and adapt it to your case. This is the example in the [Angular web](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Where `'heroes'` will be the route to HeroesComponent, so when you write in a browser `http://your-app-url/heroes` it should display that component.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Adrisons, It works for me but I don't want to create module for every component. and it is creating module every time when I am running this command. I want to only add route in app.routing.ts every time when component is created.